# How to sum a few vectors in Scala?

Tags: scala, vector, tuples

Suppose I need to sum three vectors:

```
val sum3: (Vector[Int], Vector[Int], Vector[Int]) => Vector[Int] = (v1, v2, v3) => 
  (v1 zip v2 zip v3) map {case ((x1, x2), x3) => x1 + x2 + x3}
```

if I am summing 5-6 vectors this way I am ending up with 4-5 nested tuples. Is there a better way to sum a few vectors ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vector(v1, v2, v3).transpose.map(_.sum)

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Beware if the lengths don't match: `scala> Vector(Vector(1), Vector(2,3), Vector(4)).transpose
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections have the same size`

Comment: Well summing vectors requires the vectors to have the same dimensionality by definition

Answer (score 1):

Beware of memory allocation, depending on your vector size it may not be what you want. One way to avoid it is to go fully imperative or do something like this:

```
def sum(v: Vector[Int], vs: Vector[Int]*): Vector[Int] = {
  val ixs = 0 until v.length
  for {
    _ <- v.slice(0, 1) // Hint for CanBuildFrom
    ix <- ixs
  } yield vs.foldLeft(v(ix))(_ + _(ix))
}

scala> sum(Vector(1,2,3), Vector(4,5,6), Vector(7, 8, 9))
res0: Vector[Int] = Vector(12, 15, 18)
```